# Equivalent transformer model AN1679/D

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply

I found the following transformer model in the AN1679/D written by ON SEMICONDUCTOR. The document is really interesting and very well explained.

Nevertheless, I do not understand this point, how the two model are equivalent :

[image]

If I try to put Ll2 which is at the secondary to the primary, I do not find the relation given :( Here are my calculs :

$$
\mathrm{
L_{l2}*\frac{dI_{0}}{dt} = \frac{N_{p}}{N_{s}}(V_{p}-V_{L1}) -V_{0}
}
$$

and

$$
\mathrm{
L_{l2'}*\frac{N_{s}*dI_{0}}{N_{p}*dt} = V_{p}-V_{L1} -V_{0}
}
$$

We then express each relation equal to

$$
\mathrm{
\frac{dI_{0}}{dt} = \frac{dI_{0}}{dt} 
}
$$

For express Ll2 in function of Ll2', and we get the correct relation only if Ns = 1 and Np = 1...

Did I do an error ? I m really interested by this subject !

For informations :
[image]

Thank you very much and have a nice day !

Comment: Note, you can use the \cdot operator in MathJax to create an algebraic multiply (dot) symbol. Normally these are omitted however.

Comment: I was in short trousers when I wrote this AN during the glorious MOT days : ) One little correction, the primary ohmic loss is in series with the winding not with the inductance which, alone, sits in the primary.

Comment: Hi, @VerbalKint  I did not get what you said :( Is it right or wrong what is written into your AN ? There is no primary ohmic loss in the model ? Which inductance are you talking about ? I didn't even get your expression "I was in short trousers". What does it mean in french ? ^^ Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Hello Jess, I simply meant that I wrote this application note long time ago. In figure 8, resistor Rp should not be in series with Lm: Lm should be alone and Rp in series with the upper input terminal as Rs1 in figure 11. That's all.

Comment: Ok I see ! Thank you :D

Comment: @Jess, look carefully at your added note Zout'= ?

Comment: Zout' is equat to what you say, but this work for this case and not for my case. Actually this what I think for the moment ^^ But I think you are right but i am not able to demonstrate it @skvery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are referring the secondary inductance to the primary to simplify calculations.

For an impedance $$Z = \frac{V}{I}$$.

If any impedance \$Z_s\$ on the secondary is referred to the primary the equation is:

$$Z_p = \frac{V_p/V_s}{I_p/I_s}Z_s = \frac{N_p/N_s}{N_s/N_p}Z_s = \left(\frac{N_p}{N_s}\right)^2Z_s.$$

This can also be checked by calculating a short-circuit test \$(R_\text{load}=0.)\$  The same ratios apply to the inductance \$L\$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your anwer. Your result is correct for a transformer model which is more simple than the one I showed I think.

Comment: @Jess this answer is correct. Impedance transfer between primary and secondary uses the square of the turns ratios.

Comment: @Andyaka I ask for seeing the demonstration :D and why my calcul would be wrong ...

Comment: or @skvery :D :D

Comment: @Jess your solution is over-complicating things - L1 has got nothing to do with the L2 transformation from primary to secondary - it's just turns ratio squared.

Comment: @Andyaka, see my edit, this relation applies only in this case for me ...

Comment: @Andyaka this answers requires that the voltage across Zs as skvery said in his formula equal to Vs and the current through Zs must eqaul Is, which is not the case into the above schematic ... at least for Vs ! It works if the load resistance is equal to 0 Ohm but this is not the model ...

Comment: @Jess are we done now? Did the smoke disappear?

Comment: ahaha ! Nope the smoke is still in my head ! But I am sure that I am wrong if 3 persons tell me that it is correct :D I will try to think more about it ...